# Where can I find better armor / weapons in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm level 14 and currently wearing:

- Amulet of Talos (Looted of the guy that got executed in the Solitutude)
- Elven Bow/Warhammer (Stolen from display cases)
- Imperial Boots
- Imperial Officer's Helm
- Silver Amethyst Ring
- Steel Armor
- Steel Nordic Gauntlets

Now, I can't seem to be finding apparel that has more armor or weapons that have more damage.

I feel like I have been stuck on the same equipment for some days, how do I progress?

Comment: Smithing is by far the easiest way to obtain armor and weapons. Without upgraded equipment, the armor/weapons you do find will be far weaker. There's no true way to find higher level armor/weapons, due to the fact they will start dropping at higher levels. (For example, at around 30+, ebony starts dropping at higher quantities).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is Smithing and Enchanting. Barring that, simply level up. As you do so, Merchants inventories, quest rewards, and items found in the wild will improve.

Alternately, you could pursue some of Skyrims fabulous and exotic [Artifacts](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Artifacts), which are non-levelled magical items of exceptional power. Several of the Daedric ones are particularly good.

In the case of Armor, one important thing to note is that there is technically a 'cap' of 567 Armor -  80% physical damage reduction. A fully Smithing upgraded set of Hide armor yields somewhere in the neighborhood of 700 Armor with all the appropriate perks, so realistically, you can wear whatever looks good or has enchantments that you're fond of once you have the appropriate perks and upgrade it at a workbench.

Comment: I didn't know that about the armor cap. Link?

Comment: @agf it's just math. Both the manual and strategy guide note that all resists, including physical cap out at 85%. After that, it's just a matter of crunching the numbers to see how much armor that is.

Comment: So which perk is it you need to improve Hide to Legendary? What are the other "appropriate perks" you've referenced here? I can't do it with just the steel and magic armor perks, and none of the others seem to include Hide in them. With a mix of Elven / Scaled / Glass improved to Flawless (100 Smithing), Custom Fit, and 3/5 Agile Defender for a 60% bonus (64 Light Armor), my armor rating is still only 284. I really don't want to spend the perks necessary to upgrade to Legendary / make Dragonscale. I can ask an actual question if you'd prefer.

Comment: @agf You'd need 5/5 Enchanter and some heavily enchanted +Smithing Gear at a minimum. I don't know just how OCD the fellow that produced the 700 armor hide screenshots I saw went in terms of alchemy/alchemy perks to produce +enchanting potions to improve the +smithing enchants and then +smithing potions to stack with that, but given the diminishing returns seen by doing so, you probably don't need to do *too much* of that.

Answer (score -2):

Use the Wall-breach glitch and go to the back of Skyforge and get to the secret shop chest and there should be beter gear OR find some Daugr Deathlords/ Daugr Death Overlords (they should have Ebony Two-handed/One-Handed Weapons) kill them for weapons and the first one for Gear and pickpocket Guards for a beter amulet Depending on class

PS the secret chest has gold in it so its a win and a win scenario and you can sell whats in it and replenishes with diferent gear when you exit the chest so
WIN, WIN, WIN, WIN!!! Scenario
Hope this Helped A lot if you don't know how to do the wall breach part (its a Must for chest) go to main gait of Whiterum where Guard stands go in the direction of where he is facing go right there should be a unsearchable barrel jum on it the the wall closest to the gate until you fall out then make your way to Skyforge
Hope this helped ALOT since it is Very descriptive
And
May your toast be tasty

Comment: Forgot to mention some gear in chest is enchanted :)

Answer (score -3):

The best way is to make as many dwarven bows as you can until you reach level 100