# SkyrimSE Weapon/Armor progression?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After playing the game for three days, I realised that there are a lot of weapons with the same damage, so I am quite lost in what weapon and what type of weapon to get next. I don't normaly play games like skyrim so that's why I'm quite hesitant on what to do next.

I currently have a honed ancient nord greatsword and ancient nord bow, and my armor is Silver Helmet, Steel Armor, Steel Cuffed Boots, Steel Imperial Gauntlets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I find better armor / weapons in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37155/4797)

Comment: That question has answers describing how to improve gear. This question asks about tiers and progression.

Comment: @user1337 The OP of [Where can I find better armor / weapons in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37155/4797) is talking about weapon/armor progression: "I can't seem to be finding apparel that has more armor or weapons that have more damage. I feel like I have been stuck on the same equipment for some days, **how do I progress**?"

Answer (score 1):

The weapons and armor are mostly linearly tiered and straightforward when comparing weapons between the same weapon class. [This](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Weapons#Greatswords) page covers weapons sorted by damage which generally corresponds to material tier. The order in the case of greatswords is as follows:

1. Iron Greatsword (15 base damage)
2. Steel Greatsword (17)
3. Orcish Greatsword (18)
4. Dwarven Greatsword (19)
5. Elven, Nordic, Skyforge, Nord Hero Greatswords (20 damage, sorted by weight)
6. Glass Greatsword (21)
7. Ebony Greatsword (22)
8. Stalhrim Greatsword (23)
9. Daedric Greatsword  (24)
10. Dragonbone Greatsword (25)

(a weapon with an enchantment might be more powerful than a basic one of a lower tier)

While the progression is similar across types, other weapon types like one-handed swords and greataxes have different base stats such as range and attack speed that balance out their damage which might leave you with the impression that a big, low-tier two-handed hits as hard as a medium-tier one-handed. Couple that with weapon skills and the order stops being apparent across 1h/2h weapons.

Ultimately both for weapons and armor, you can just wear whatever has the biggest numbers as long as you can lift it. It's not something that should require a lot of thought put into it.

Comment: My advice: Pick either one-handed or two-handed, then use whatever has the best numbers in that class until you start taking weapon-specific perks (which you should not do right away, because there are several other perks which are more beneficial overall). For armor, pick light or heavy and just use whatever has the biggest numbers. If you want to sneak, you should probably pick light armor (or a muffle-enchanted item) and one-handed weapons (general weapon perks stack with the backstab bonuses in the sneak tree, but the latter are mostly exclusive to one-handed weapons).